# phonegap jquery mobile css not loaded on ios device (works in emulator)

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Weird problem everything works fine on emulator, but when I try to run the applicaiton on device, all jquerymobile css file is not applied, other part of code still works, just no css style. it seem css file is never loaded.

jquery 1.8.1
jquerymobile 1.3.1
phonegap 1.9

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A navigation-view template generated by MyEclipse Mobile Tools"/>
    <!-- <script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#dongdh"></script>  -->
    <!-- Load jquery css files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/library/jQuery/jquerymobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/library/jQuery/jquerymobile-structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/library/jQuery/jquerymobile-theme.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/library/phonegap/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/library/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/library/jquery/jquerymobile.js"></script>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady()
    {
      //Phonegap is ready
      alert("Phonegap is ready");
    }

    $(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        console.log("Initialize jQuery Mobile Phonegap Enhancement Configurations")
        // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
    });
    </script>

    <!-- use require.js to load system -->
    <!-- <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/library/require/require.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script data-main="js/jm_requirejs_test.js" src="js/library/require/require.js"></script> -->
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="main_body">
<div data-role="page" id="index_container">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    test
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    test
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="fool" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="loading_container"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="main_container"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="login_container"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="userprofile_container"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="tutorial_container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show us your code? your HTML, css, maybe a screenshot of the "not working" part on your phone. or even maybe a fiddle. Only then your questions will get more traction around here.

Comment: I got this solved, I had wrong versin of jquery with jquerymobile, and ios didnt like it..